# How to install gcc3.4 on a new Ubuntu OS?

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-14.04

How to install gcc3.4? I need this version to compile u-boot sources which seem to take older version of gcc.

I have a fresh install of 0S - Ubuntu-mate 14.04.2-LTS, which I am using to install gcc3.4. I do not have any pre installed gcc on this.

When I tried the command:

```
$sudo apt-get install gcc-3.4
```

I am getting the error:

> E: Unable to locate package gcc-3.4
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-3.4'

Comment: There are no gnu toolchain packages older than 4.4 for Ubuntu 12. You will need a different route.

Comment: Okey, What route should I go ?

Comment: Build it from source is one option.